# retrieve image path from sqlite in image adapter (GridView on Xamarin Android C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to display my picture in the gridview. The picture is coming from the path and the path is stored in the SQLite database. I try the tutorial from MSDN here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view and I modified and changed my resource.drawable.image into the image path (the image path is from the database), but I don't know how to do that. I try using the bitmap method but I still confused about how I can make it array using this method. I want to get the picture data such as photo title, photo description, and photo path from the database and store it into my List<> or array.

I already make the database and try to call it but, I still confused. Please help me.

So, this is an object class for the table. It called Photo.cs

```
[Table("tblPhoto")]
    public class Photo
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("pkPhotoID")]
        public int PhotoID { get; set; }
    [Column("fkUserID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoDescription { get; set; }
    private DateTime _creationDate;

    public string CreationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate.ToString(); }
        set { _creationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", null); }
    }

    private DateTime _uploadDate;
    public string UploadDate
    {
        get { return _uploadDate.ToString(); }
        set { _uploadDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }
    //show User Photo
    public static Photo ShowUserPhoto()
    {
        return DBManager.Instance.Query<Photo>($"SELECT * FROM tblPhoto a JOIN tblUser b WHERE a.UserID== b.UserID").FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //show photo path and its photo
    public static Photo ShowPhotoPath(string aPhotoPath)
    {
        return DBManager.Instance.Query<Photo>($"SELECT * FROM tblPhoto WHERE PhotoPath=='{aPhotoPath}'").FirstOrDefault();
    }

    //show all
    public static Photo ShowAllPhoto()
    {
        return DBManager.Instance.Query<Photo>($"SELECT * FROM tblPhoto").FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

and the second is for ImageAdapter because I want to display the picture in gridview. It called the ImageAdapter.cs

```
public class ImageAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private List<string> gridViewString;
        private List<string> gridViewImage;
        public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<string> gridViewstr, List<string> gridViewImage)
        {
            this.context = context;
            gridViewString = gridViewstr;
            this.gridViewImage = gridViewImage;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return gridViewString.Count;
            }
        }
    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            view = new View(context);
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.gridview_layout, null);
            TextView txtview = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textPhotoTitleViewGrid);
            ImageView imgview = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewGrid);

            txtview.Text = gridViewString[position];
            imgview.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromDB(gridViewImage[position]));
        }
        else
        {
            view = (View)convertView;
        }
        return view;
    }

    private Android.Graphics.Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromDB(string aPath)
    {
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        var _getPath = Model.Photo.ShowPhotoPath(aPath);
        {
            var imgPath = _getPath.ShowPhotoPath(aPath);
            if (imgPath != null && imgPath.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgPath);
            }
        }
        return imageBitmap;
    }
}
```

and the last is a fragment class called Fragment_home.cs The image should be displayed here

```
public class Fragment_Home : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        List<string> m_gridviewstring = new List<string>();
        List<string> m_imgview = new List<string>();
        GridView m_gridview;
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle aSavedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(aSavedInstanceState);
        }

        public static Fragment_Home NewInstance()
        {
            var _frag1 = new Fragment_Home { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return _frag1;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater aInflater, ViewGroup aContainer, Bundle aSavedInstanceState)
        {
            var _ignored = base.OnCreateView(aInflater, aContainer, aSavedInstanceState);
            //String stringData = Arguments.GetString("email");
            View _view =  aInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentHome, null);

            //var gridview = _view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);
            //gridview.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(Context);

            //gridview.ItemClick += Gridview_ItemClick;

            //return _view;

            var _retrievePic = Model.Photo.ShowAllPhoto();
            //_retrievePic.PhotoPath;

            ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(Activity, m_gridviewstring, m_imgview);
            m_gridview = _view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.grid_view_image_text);
            m_gridview.Adapter = adapter;
            return _view;
        }
    }
```

Please help me, any help?

Comment: Can you share a image storage path to make a test, If I store the image to `"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures"` path, we can read it by following code.`Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile);  imageView.SetImageBitmap(myBitmap);` Normally, if we want to storage Image to DB, we do not use file path, we used Base64( convert the bitmap to Base64 string to storage Base64 string to DB, if we want read it from DB, we can read the Base64 string from DB, then convert base64 string to bitmap)

Comment: Alright, my image storage is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200430_212854.jpg` I hope it works.. but, I think it's possible to use path because we can decode the string path into an image by using `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(mypath);` right?

Comment: Ok, please wait serveral minutes, I post a answer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post two images in `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/` path and `"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures"` path as well. For testing, I re-name Photo names.

Here is running gif(Please ignore the nest fragments, I do not want to create a new demo from start to end,I used my previous demo).

[image]

Firstly, I create a `PhotoDAO.cs`, it will insert data to DB and read all of data from DB. I have given a PhotoPath and PhotoName when insert data to DB.

```
  public class PhotoDAO
    {
      static  SQLiteConnection db;

        public List<Photo> GetAllPhotos()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading data");
            var table = db.Table<Photo>();
            List<Photo> photos = table.ToList<Photo>();


            return photos;
        }
        public static void DoSomeDataAccess()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating database, if it doesn't already exist");
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(
                 System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                 "Photo1.db3");
            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<Photo>();
            if (db.Table<Photo>().Count() == 0)
            {
                // only insert the data if it doesn't already exist
                var newPhoto1 = new Photo();
                newPhoto1.UserID = 1;
                newPhoto1.PhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/";
                newPhoto1.PhotoName = "icon.png";
                newPhoto1.PhotoDescription = "This is a hamburger";
                db.Insert(newPhoto1);

                var newPhoto2 = new Photo();
                newPhoto2.UserID = 2;
                newPhoto2.PhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/";
                newPhoto2.PhotoName = "person.jpg";
                newPhoto2.PhotoDescription = "This is a person";
                db.Insert(newPhoto2);

                var newPhoto3 = new Photo();
                newPhoto3.UserID = 3;
                newPhoto3.PhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";
                newPhoto3.PhotoName = "IMG1.jpg";
                newPhoto3.PhotoDescription = "This is a IMG1";
                db.Insert(newPhoto3);

                var newPhoto4 = new Photo();
                newPhoto4.UserID = 4;
                newPhoto4.PhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/";
                newPhoto4.PhotoName = "IMG2.jpg";
                newPhoto4.PhotoDescription = "This is a IMG2";
                db.Insert(newPhoto4);

            }  
        }
    }
```

Then in the `Fragment_Gallery.cs`, we set a `Adapter` for `GridView`. Here is code.

```
    public class Fragment_Gallery : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }
        public static Fragment_Gallery NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment_Gallery { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.galleryfragment, null);

            var gridview = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);

            PhotoDAO.DoSomeDataAccess();
            var photoDAO=new PhotoDAO();
            List<Photo> photos=photoDAO.GetAllPhotos();
            gridview.Adapter = new MyAdapter(this, photos);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Here is code about my gridview Adapter. I create a CustomView for test if you need custom the item in gridview in the future. I set Imageview source from local path, please see  `GetView` method.

```
    internal class MyAdapter :BaseAdapter<Photo>
    {
        private Fragment_Gallery fragment_Gallery;
        private List<Photo> photos;

        public MyAdapter(Fragment_Gallery fragment_Gallery, List<Photo> photos)
        {
            this.fragment_Gallery = fragment_Gallery;
            this.photos = photos;
        }

        public override Photo this[int position] => photos[position];

        public override int Count => photos.Count;



        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
           return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = fragment_Gallery.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.custUserID).Text = photos[position].UserID.ToString();
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.custPhotoPath).Text = photos[position].PhotoPath;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.custPhotoName).Text = photos[position].PhotoName;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.custPhotoDescription).Text = photos[position].PhotoDescription;
            string imgFile = photos[position].PhotoPath + photos[position].PhotoName;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile);

            view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.custImage).SetImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            return view;
        }


    }
```

Here is layout about `CustomView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView  
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" 
    android:id="@+id/custImage" />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/custUserID" 
    android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/custPhotoPath" 
    android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/custPhotoName" 
    android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
    />
        <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/custPhotoDescription" 
    android:text="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

In the end, please do not forget to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Here is my demo, you can download it and make a test(Please add Images like my PersonDAO class or you can change the name of image in PersonDAO class).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ipw534Q0C4UxHva3Jiv5SoI0KycifpmI/view?usp=sharing

**=====update=======**

If you want to achieve the click event, you can use `gridview.ItemClick += Gridview_ItemClick;` to achieve it. If you got image position from the adapter is not found, please add a break point `Photo photo = photos[e.Position];` in the `Gridview_ItemClick`, if you got the e.Position correctly.

```
   public class Fragment_Gallery : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }
        public static Fragment_Gallery NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new Fragment_Gallery { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }
        List<Photo> photos;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.galleryfragment, null);

            GridView gridview = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview);
            gridview.ItemClick += Gridview_ItemClick;

            PhotoDAO.DoSomeDataAccess();
            var photoDAO=new PhotoDAO();
            photos=photoDAO.GetAllPhotos();

            gridview.Adapter = new MyAdapter(this, photos);
            return view;
        }

        private void Gridview_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();

            Photo photo = photos[e.Position];
            Intent intent= new Intent(Context, typeof(DetailActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("PicName", photo.PhotoName);
            intent.PutExtra("PicDes", photo.PhotoDescription);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

In the DetailActivity, you can got the picture info by following code.

```
   public class DetailActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Detaillayout);
            TextView detailPhotoName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailPhotoName);
            TextView detailPhotoDescription = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.detailPhotoDescription);

            Bundle extras =Intent.Extras;
            detailPhotoName.Text = extras.GetString("PicName");
            detailPhotoDescription.Text = extras.GetString("PicDes");
            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

You want to display the picture bigger in the fragment layout or the `DetailActivity`? In the fragment layout, just set bigger value for `columnWidth=200dp` in `GridView` and Open the `CustomView.xml`, set bigger value for `android:layout_width="200dp"  android:layout_height="200dp"` in `ImageView`

Here is click running gif.

[image]

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept this answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: hello, sorry for the late response. Yeah! It helps me a lot. Thank you very much for your help. But, I want to ask more. I want to display the picture bigger and its details like picture name and the description in the next activity by the picture or the adapter are clicked.. but I got any errors like the image position from the adapter is not found. and Honestly, I feel a bit confused.. would you like to help me? give me insight? thanks before

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer! Yeah, It works! Thank you very much for your help! God Bless you, Man! :D